# Kibana unable to search message field

Tags: elk, kibana-7

I am trying to search message field like this in Kibana search bar.

```
message: "*CannotCreateTransactionException*" .
```

It is unable to search it , while it works for :-

```
message: "org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException"
```

Complete message field is :-

[http-nio-8080-exec-31] {ERROR} - Forwarding to error page from request due to exception [Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: ]
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:582) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]

Answer (score 0):

My bad , quotes consider * as part of string

Solution is

```
message: *CannotCreateTransactionException*
```